# Empty? fails on ActiveRecord with a default_scope( :order)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, default-scope

Occasionally I want to check whether a Person model has any organizations. Straightforward enough; use `@person.organizations.empty?`. However, coupled with my default_scope (`default_scope { order(:name) }`), I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
>   LINE 1: ... WHERE "relationships"."person_id" = $1  ORDER BY "organizat...
>                                                                ^
>
> : SELECT  DISTINCT 1 AS one FROM "organizations" INNER JOIN "contracts" ON "organizations"."id" = "contracts"."organization_id" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "contracts"."id" = "relationships"."contract_id" WHERE "relationships"."person_id" = $1  ORDER BY "organizations"."name" ASC LIMIT 1):

I'm using a Postgres DB and my (abbreviated) model setup looks as follows:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contracts
  has_many :people, -> { uniq }, :through => :contracts

  default_scope { order(:name) }
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of => :person
  has_many :contracts, :through => :relationships
  has_many :organizations, -> { uniq }, :through => :contracts
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, touch: true

  has_many :relationships, :inverse_of => :contract
  has_many :people, :through => :relationships
end
```

Things I have tried so far:

```
  has_many :organizations, -> { order(:name).uniq }, :through => :contracts
```

Which supposedly would make activerecord see what was coming in advance (it didn't) and

```
  has_many :organizations, -> { includes(:name).uniq }, :through => :contracts
```

which fixes the problem when I put it in manually in the console, but does not help in the app itself. How do I coerce ActiveRecord into formatting the `empty?` query differently or dropping the order whenever I am using `empty?`?

EDIT: To be clear, I am perfectly aware that using `@person.organizations.count == 0` will work, and there are probably other  one-off solutions. But I'm looking for a general one so I don't have to keep repeating myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@person.organizations.reorder('').empty?
```

should work

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that will make this usable in general; this codebase is fractured enough without having to put signposts up to say 'if you want to check this for emptiness, use count ==0 or reorder'

Comment: what version of rails are you using?